# Error while converting leads to account and contact using Database.LeadConvert class

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

I am using Database.LeadConvert  class to convert leads to accounts and contacts. But getting a validation rule Error while inserting account because there is a required field missing [standard field] 'Description' while creating an account. How to map a lead field to account's required field [standard field :Description]?

Comment: It is for standard field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope the following article will help

[ARTICLE FOR LEAD FIELD MAP](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_mapleads.htm&type=0)

Answer (score 1):

Any custom fields that have been marked as required will need to be manually mapped for lead conversion.

1. Setup > Customize > Leads > Fields
2. Scroll down to Lead Custom Fields & Relationships and click Map Lead Fields.
3. For each custom lead field, choose a custom account, contact, or opportunity field into which you want the information inserted when you convert a lead.
4. Save your work.

Note: These stpes are for Salesforce Classic.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I searched for the reason and see this is what I found. You can focus on the steps other than data load etc where they mention about the field creation.

Here's the link:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004968&type=1

Let me know if this helps you!

Further help: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214805&type=1